# How to calculate mutual index of concidence of two strings Java

Tags: java, cryptography

i am trying to calculate the mutual index of concidence of two strings, A and B. I have calculated the frequency of each letter in each string. However, i do not know how to continue from there. Any help is appreciated. The expected output is supposed to be some decimal value. Thanks!

```
public class MutualIndexOfAB
{
public double calculateMutual(String a, String b)
{
    int i, j;
    int NA = 0;
    int NB = 0;
    double sum = 0.0, total = 0.0;
    a = a.toUpperCase();
    b = b.toUpperCase();


    // calculate frequency of each letter in String a 
    int chA;
    for (i=0; i<a.length(); i++)
    {
        ch = a.charAt(i)-65;
        if (chA>=0 && chA <26)
        {
            values[chA]++;
            NA++;
        }
    }


    // calculate frequency of each letter in String b 
    int chB;
    for (j=0; j<b.length(); j++)
    {
        chB = b.charAt(j)-65;
        if (chB>=0 && chB <26)
        {
            values[chB]++;
            NB++;
        }
    }


}



public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MutualIndexOfAB test = new MutualIndexOfAB();

    String textA = "cyber security is about how we develop secure computers and computer networks, to ensure that the data stored and transmitted through them is protected from unauthorized access or to combat digital security threats and hazards. as we conduct more of our social, consumer and business activities online, there is a corresponding increase in the demand for ict professionals to manage our digital environment and economy.";

    String textB = "cyber security has been identified as one of the strategic priorities in australia to meet the demands of law enforcement, national and state governments, defense, security and finance industries. jobs of the future will be in all of these areas ensuring there is national capability to maintain and build our essential services and stop them from being disrupted, destroyed, or threatened, and that our personal information is not communicated, shared, visualized or analysed without our permission.";

    System.out.println("Mutual Index of Concidence of Texts A and B: " + test.calculateMutual(textA, textB));
}
```

}

Comment: What is the "mutual index of concidence of two string"? Please [edit] your question and include sample input and the expected result.

Comment: @LutzHorn https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence used in breaking substitution ciphers

Comment: @Michael OK. What does this tell us about the expected result for `textA` and `textB`?

Comment: Actually, OP is asking "mutual index of concidence of two strings", not "index of concidence".

Comment: @Maximus The technique of mutual IoC is still described in the article I linked to. "coincidence counting is the technique ... of putting two texts side-by-side and counting the number of times that identical letters appear in the same position in both texts".

Comment: @LutzHorn The strings start with the same phrase then diverge, so slightly above 1/26

Comment: @Michael Oh right, didn't check it, just thought I'd mention because I saw the link.

Comment: @Michael There is also this: http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~debdeep/courses_iitkgp/Crypto/slides/cryptanalysis.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a single loop with an index (instead of two), and then compare the characters of each string, increasing a counter if they match. Then perform division by the total number of characters.